# How to change computer setting remotely

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, networking, remote-access

I would like to setup a web server on my HTPC that I can use to handle various tasks such as changing the default audio output or adjusting the display to output to only one screen without having to actually touch the machine.

While I understand the actual programming may be difficult itself, my main focus is learning how one can go about handling various events. I have initially set up a IIS server and created a site to handle all the events on my HTPC.  The site is only accessible through the intranet and knowledge of the specific port. Ideally, the solution would be that you access the HTPC local ip address with the specified port and are presented with options(buttons) to either set default audio device, display etc. (This will probably involve some html programming but it is feasible to leverage a java script or is asp.net the language I should write in)

Any help would be appreciative as I know its possible to set up a server to handle events/requests - I just don't know where to begin or what to start reading up on.

Comment: Did you think of trying Powershell for these tasks?

Comment: What about setting up Django to run python scripts on your server?

Comment: nphx - I haven't messed with powershell so ill have to read up on it, but with skimming through real quick that looks like an option, however, with my lazy self, I would like to be able to access the url from my phone and be able to click a button that corresponds to a specific task which i believe is where powershell would come into play

Answer (score 0):

if it can be done via the command line, generally it can be done via asp (on the server).

you need to give the application pool that the website will be running under permissions on your computer to be able to carry out the tasks (if you're lazy and don't care about security make it run as you)

you then simple need to write a process that starts up either a cmd process or powershell instance in the button click event handler.

For powershell, i've followed [Jeff Murrs example](http://jeffmurr.com/blog/?p=142) in the past and had success.

For command line processes it is similar but you use System.Diagnostics.Process.

This should be enough for you to research and hopefully get something